# Typhoon - Creating View Controllers with initWithNib - XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, typhoon

I'm using the last 1.x version of Typhoon that supports XML definition.  Every time a new version of iOS betas come around, our Typhoon implementation starts breaking down.  *Usually* by the iOS GM, most of the issues go away, or we find a *legitimate* work around.

One issue that has come up multiple times (and always resolved itself) is in our constructing of view controllers.  My question is whether there is a better way to define the XML (I'm just worried that one of these versions of iOS will permanently break our code).  My view controller is defined as:

```
<component class="MyViewController" key="my_view_controller">
    <initializer selector="initWithNibName:bundle:">
        <argument parameterName="nibName" value="MyNibName" required-class="NSString" />
    </initializer>
</component>
```

Is there a better way to define this initializer?  I realize that one argument is being passed to a two argument method.  I need that second argument to be 'nil' and my understanding is that by leaving it blank, 'nil' is ultimately used.  But every time, around beta 2 or 3 of the new iOS, these view controllers start breaking.  Currently, with iOS9 and beta 6, this is fixed again, but is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

In Typhoon 2.x and onward it is possible (and necessary) to inject nil explicitly, as not specifiying an argument no longer implies nil. This is to help prevent config errors.

For your particular use-case, I believe nil here implies that `[NSBundle mainBundle] should be used. So it would be worth defining a definition for main bundle and injecting that.

```
<component class="NSBundle" key="mainBundle">
    <initializer selector="mainBundle"/>
</component>
```